# Return only numeric values from column - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have several values in my `name` column within the `contacts` table similar to this one:

`test 3100509 DEMO NPS`

I want to return only the numeric piece of each value from `name`.

I tried this:

`select substring(name FROM '^[0-9]+|.*') from contacts`

But that doesn't do it.

Any thoughts on how to strip all characters that are not numeric from the returned values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this :

```
select substring(name FROM '[0-9]+') from contacts
```

Comment: not the best answer. if I put: `select substring('998343913-15' from '[0-9]+')` I get `998343913` and not `99834391315`

Answer (score 14):

`select regexp_replace(name , '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') from contacts;`

This should do it. It will work even if you have more than one numeric sequences in the name.

Example:

```
create table contacts(id int, name varchar(200));

insert into contacts(id, name) values(1, 'abc 123 cde 555 mmm 999');

select regexp_replace(name , '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') from contacts;
```

Comment: +1 And maybe even with a [regexp class shorthand](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE): `SELECT regexp_replace(name, '\D', '', 'g') FROM contacts;`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the numeric values with decimal point than use this

```
select NULLIF(regexp_replace(name, '[^0-9.]*','','g'), '')::numeric from contacts
```